# Spring boot / MySQL and Docker issue

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a spring boot application (jar) as a docker container! The spring boot app connects to a MySQL database to manage data! So basically two containers are involved, one for the spring boot app and one for MySQL!

## Spring boot app environment:

-- Created using eclipse

-- OS : Under my Windows machine!

-- application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeedb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
server.port=8081
```

-- Test the app to make sure everything is OK!

## Docker environment:

-- Installed in x.x.x.x server: OS : Centos! (NOT Windows)

-- Dockerfile for spring boot app:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD app/springbootrest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar springboot-rest-docker.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-rest-docker.jar"]
docker build . -t springboot-rest-docker
docker run -p 8081:8081 -name springboot-rest-docker-app -d springboot-rest-docker
```

-- MySQL container:

```
docker container run --name mysqldb --network springbootrest-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=employeedb -d mysql
```

## Issue:

I cannot update MySQL host from "localhost" to "mysqldb" in my application.properties because the MySQL container is running on a remote centos server!

## What I'm asking:

Is there any way to externalize the application.properties to link the two containers the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access MySQL from your Host OS. ie. Windows. If not. you can't connect both with current setup.

Comment: Hello @MyTwoCents, thank you for your reply, Actually, I choose this setup cuz I can't install Docker on my windows machine (Family version). I have no idea how to test the connection between the remote MySQL container and my local windows machine!

Comment: ok. So where is this Docker Server? On cloud or in another system at your home,  You can ping IP in windows cmd to check if its accessible,

Comment: The docker is installed in a remote centos server! Actually the application is developed in my local windows machine, this is why I used : mysql://LOCALHOST:3306/employeedb for testing purpose! after making sure that everything works, I packaged my spring boot app as a JAR file! Now I want to use Docker to deploy the app, this why I'm asking if there is any way to override the datasource property : mysql://LOCALHOST:3306/employeedb at runtime when running the app image in docker so it can connect to " prod mysql container" !

Comment: Hello, I fixed the issue using : "Dspring.profiles.active=prod" in Dockerfile! that way Docker will build the image using "application-prod.properties" where I configured mysql://mysql-container:3306/employeedb!